# How to get the generated ID of an auto increment column after insertion of a record in HSQLDB within same connection?

Tags: auto-increment, hsqldb, embedded-database

I have created a table as

```
    create table test(log_id integer identity primary_key, filename varchar, filecontent blob)
```

Now my query in java inserts values in test using prepared statement as

```
    insert into test(filename, filecontent) values (?,?);
```

After insertion I want to know what is the log_id of this latest inserted record while being in same db connection because;
based on this log_ID I want to insert another child record with same log_id as foreign key in another table?
I checked the call identity() method but i don't know how to use it in java code and get the returned value?
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `identity()` method in the next INSERT statement for the child table. In this example the child table has a ref_id column for the foreign key plus a data_col for its data. The child table has its own primary key column and a foreign key column that references the log_id column of the test table.

```
create table child(child_id integer identity primary_key, ref_id integer, data_col varchar);
alter table child add constraint child_fk foreign key (ref_id) references test(log_id);
insert into child(ref_id, data_col) values (identity(), ?);
```

Comment: By ref_id you mean my log_id column..right? (which is acting as primary key in table "TEST" and same I want to act as foreign key in table "CHILD_TEST")

Comment: No. ref_id is a column in the CHILD table that references log_id in the TEST table. I added some code to make it clear.